# How to change lunarvim native colors to match neovim?

Tags: lua, neovim, lunarvim

I'm using `lunarvim` and don't want to utilize `TreeSitter` for color management. I like the `pablo` colorscheme and in both `vim` and `nvim` the colors show up just fine, but in `lvim` the colors change. Specifically, the blue color is very hard to read as in the example below.

What `lunarvim` settings do I change to either modify this blue color (`seq` in the example below) or change them back to the ones that both `nvim` and `vim` use?

`nvim` colors:

[image]

`lvim` colors:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a simple 'click this button' answer, but I resolved the issue as follows:

In vim / lunarvim, you can see how the coloring is defined simply by `:hi`. In my case, I found multiple entries which had the annoying blue color and changed them one by one until it showed up as I liked.

In my case I simply added the following line to my `~/.config/lvim/config.lua` as part of the `lvim.autocommands = {` portion:

```
{ "ColorScheme", { pattern = { "*" }, command = "highlight Special guifg=#5c5cff" } },
```